# Inheritance of POCO objects in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, poco

I'm trying to solve the following problem using EF, code first and pocos:

Let's say that I have an application that must serve different customers. Each customer gets its own database and model, so I will create one model and one repository project per customer.

The problem is - where should I put business code common to all installations? In traditional OOP I would have one class library with bunch of base classes defining basic behavior - e.g. UserBase, ArticleBase, constants, utility methods etc. Then in customer specific project I would inherit a class from that base class and extend its data and behavior e.g. Client1User : User or Client1Article : ArticleBase.

My first idea was to have common class library with edmx file defining base classes and their relations. With tt template I generated POCO classes and optionally added some custom code.
In my custom library made for each client I referenced that base library and created specific classes inherited from common library or totally new classes. In custom library I  also created customer specific edmx and used t4 template to generate POCOs. 
I also created separate repository project to handle persistence and querying. 
In repository class I have bunch of DbSet ClassnameSet properties that I should be able to query.

The problem is I can't do that and I constantly bump to an Metadataexception - Class A is not part of the current model or

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  The relationship 'xxx' was not
>   loaded because the type 'model.User' is not available. The following
>   information may be useful in resolving the previous error: The base
>   type 'BaseLibrary.BaseUser' of type 'ClientLibrary.Model.User' does
>   not match the model base type 'model.User'.

Thanks for any help in resolving this mystery. Or for pointing me in different direction to achieve my goal.

Tvrtko

Comment: I would recommend putting the base classes in the same library for a test, EF needs to be able to reflection load the classes which may be where your issue is comming from if it doesnt have the assembly loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by thinking about your "architecture". Having separate model and "repository" for each customer is overkill. [Use single data access layer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72685/branching-model-suggestion-for-same-project-multiple-clients) and make your application configurable and extensible to support needs of all your customers.

The problem with this scenario is type inheritance between base library and client library. First of all you will not be able to have EDMX in base library - you will have to create new in each client library. You will also have to make decision if you want to use client specific types or base types in the mapping. Using base types means using inheritance mapping for every entity. Using client types probably results in you current exception - your base types probably defines navigation properties pointing to other base types - that is not possible if you don't map base types in client library.